# *ngFor needs to pruduce 1 btn for each different object, but put similar object value within the same btn

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, algorithm, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app that will list of classes for a teacher on a chosen day, each class being a button on the screen. This list is made using `*ngFor` and pulls data from a ts file, that originally came from a PHP/database query.

The button would then be pressed by the teacher to show which students should be in class that day. It is an attendance/absence monitoring app.

However, I am testing the `*ngFor` to make my list, and because the data is stored as 3 objects, each with info for a student, three buttons are being created dynamically by the `*ngFor` - when in fact, as the three students are in the same class, I need just one button.

The next button would only need to be created for the teacher's next class that day.

This is an algorithm problem I guess, or possibly there is a different query to be made to get the data from SQL. I don't know.

I am lost.

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card padding *ngFor="let cour of planning; let i = index" (click)="showStudents($event, i)">
        <h2>{{ cour.cours }}</h2>
        <p>{{ cour.time }}</p>
        <p>{{ cour.date }}</p>
        <p>{{ cour.lieux }}</p>
        <p>{{ cour.duration }}</p>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Service

```
getCoursList(date, idIntervenant) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/Attendance App/myApp/src/app/api/getCours.php?id='+idIntervenant,
        { date, }).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(Object.values(data));
            let planningData = Object.values(data);
            const grabArray = planningData[0];
            const id = grabArray.intervenant;
            if (id !== undefined) {
                // console.log('test array', id);
                let navExtras: NavigationExtras = { 
                state: {
                    planning: planningData
                }
                }
                this.router.navigate(['/cours/', id], navExtras);
            };
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

PHP query to database

```
if (isset($_POST["date"])) {
    // $id = $_POST["id"];
    $origDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $date = $origDate;
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM planning WHERE intervenant = :id AND date = :date");
    $stmt->execute([':id' => $id, ':date' => $date]);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $output = array();
        $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($output);
    } else {
        $errors = "No data found for this date";
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
    // $conn->close();
}
```

Data received from PHP query - 1 array containing 3 objects

```
[object Array]: [Object, Object, Object]

0: Object
cours: "Suivi individuel"
date: "2019-07-06"
duration: "1h30"
etudiant: "james ross"
id_planning: 19
intervenant: "2"
lieux: "Nice 2"
time: "12:00"

__proto__: Object

1: Object
cours: "Suivi individuel"
date: "2019-07-06"
duration: "1h30"
etudiant: "Tupac Shakur"
id_planning: 20
intervenant: "2"
lieux: "Nice 2"
time: "12:00"

__proto__: Object


2: Object
cours: "Suivi individuel"
date: "2019-07-06"
duration: "1h30"
etudiant: "Joyner lucas"
id_planning: 21
intervenant: "2"
lieux: "Nice 2"
time: "12:00"

__proto__: Object
length: "3"
```

The three students above are all going to the same class, at the same time etc, so I want only one button to be produced dynamically.

If the teacher had a second lesson that day, it would produce a second button, and so on.

At present there are no error messages, I am just not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may need to structure your database differently. Instead of having a row for each student in the planning Table consider going to the following structure:

```
Table Student:
- studentId
- name

Table Teacher:
- teacherId
- name

Table Class:
- classId
- name
- description
- schedule (not sure what the format of this would be,
    but using it your code should be able to determine the next meeting of the class)

Table Registration (each row in this table represents a student enrolled in the class):
- classId
- teacherId
- studentId
```

Then your query becomes `SELECT * FROM Class WHERE teacherId=X` X being the logged in teacher. This would give you the total list of classes the teacher has.

To get a list of students in a particular class you can then do: `SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE classId=Y AND teacherId=X` Y being one of the class Ids retrieved from the previous query.

Hope this helps you get headed in the right direction!

Comment: Yes, I think the restructuring of the databases is the way to go. Thank you.